# Linux "uniq -d" command equivalent for PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, shell

I try to write a script in PowerShell which finds files that have same names. After that I want to know how many duplicate names of group that files. I succeded to finding files like that:

```
foreach ($i in Get-ChildItem *.)
{
    Write-Host (Get-ChildItem $i).BaseName
}
```

But after that I need a command like in Linux `cat file | sort | uniq -d`. This `-d` parameter is my goal in PS.

I tried following command, but doesn't work:

```
$var = (Write-Host (Get-ChildItem $i).BaseName | Sort-Object -Unique).Count

# Let's say there are files '1.mp4,1.mkv,2.mp4'
# I want variable var's value is 1, because only one group that has same file names
```

Comment: Your question is not clear - "I want variable var's value is 1, because only one group that has same file names" Is the `1` numeric because there is 1 group or is is meant to be the BaseName of the file that has duplicate names? if there are 2 groups with duplicate BaseNames are you looking for `2` as the answer or 2 different `BaseName`s? Please can you [edit] the question to clarify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do what you need,

```
$var = Get-ChildItem | Group-Object -Property BaseName | Where-Object { $_.Count -gt 1} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

#### I tried following command, but doesn't work:

> ```
> $var = (Write-Host (Get-ChildItem $i).BaseName | Sort-Object -Unique).Count
> ```
>
> # I want variable var's value is 1, because only one group that has same file names

The other answer by jfrmilner stores the `BaseName` in `var` **not** the count as you have requested in the question.

The following command stores the count (number of distinct sets of files sharing a command BaseName) in `var`, which may be a more useful general command:

```
 $var = (Get-ChildItem $i).BaseName | Group-Object | ?{ $_.Count -gt 1 } | Measure-Object | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Count
```

**Example 1 - One set of files sharing a common basename (test)**

```
> Get-ChildItem


    Directory: F:\test


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       12/02/2020     12:18           1272 test.txt
-a----       16/02/2020     17:51             72 test.cmd
-a----       19/11/2019     21:50             19 output.txt
-a----       08/12/2019     18:47            119 GetBits.cmd
-a----       31/12/2019     14:31       26876158 SystemEvents.xml
-a----       08/01/2020     21:30            845 notepad++ regexp answer template.txt
-a----       12/02/2020     11:00          17755 usb.csv
-a----       01/03/2020     10:05            264 index.jpg
-a----       01/03/2020     10:09            264 New.txt


> (Get-ChildItem $i).BaseName | Group-Object | ?{ $_.Count -gt 1 } | Measure-Object | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Count
1
>
```

**Example 2 - Two sets of files sharing a common basename (test and New)**

```
> Get-ChildItem


    Directory: F:\test


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       12/02/2020     12:18           1272 test.txt
-a----       16/02/2020     17:51             72 test.cmd
-a----       19/11/2019     21:50             19 output.txt
-a----       08/12/2019     18:47            119 GetBits.cmd
-a----       31/12/2019     14:31       26876158 SystemEvents.xml
-a----       08/01/2020     21:30            845 notepad++ regexp answer template.txt
-a----       12/02/2020     11:00          17755 usb.csv
-a----       01/03/2020     10:05            264 index.jpg
-a----       01/03/2020     10:09            264 New.txt
-a----       08/03/2020     15:35              0 1
-a----       08/03/2020     15:52              0 New.xxx


> (Get-ChildItem $i).BaseName | Group-Object | ?{ $_.Count -gt 1 } | Measure-Object | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Count
2
>
```

Comment: Read the question again. "1" is the example _BaseName_ that is shared by multiple files. So the first answer is closer, even though he lists the names of the files that share the `BaseName`.

Comment: @KeithMiller Ah. Question is a little unclear then ... as his example code is ending with `Count` ...

Comment: Never look at the OP's code, it will just confuse you! :D

Comment: @KeithMiller I've asked for clarity, so we will see ...

Comment: Most likely, the OP just needed to be made aware of the `Group-Object` cmdlet. He knew what he wanted, just not that familiar with PowerShell.